# Validation on Email works first time

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi all JavaScript Gurus,

I am doing some Inline Validation using pure JavaScript for Email. While i do testing for the first time it shows all the validation fine, after entering of valid email , if i delete valid email (coming back to this input box after visiting other input box in form) and enter in-valid email or delete an valid one it does not show up the validation at all. Please note this is nothing to do with submit button.

```
function validateEmail(){ 
  var userEmail = document.getElementById('email');
  var errorE = document.getElementById('emailError');
  var validEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if(!validEmail.test(userEmail.value)){
    errorE.classList.remove('display');
    errorE.classList.add('validation');
    return false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<p>
    <label class='label' for='email'>
        Email
    </label>
    <input type='text' id='email' name='email' onblur="validateEmail(email)"> 
    <span id="emailError" class="display">
        You must enter a valid email address
    </span>
</p>
```

Please guide me on this as i am new and learning javascript

Comment: shouldn't you use reverse function for test passed? `errorE.classList.remove('validation');errorE.classList.add('display');`

Comment: If you are setting the element with id `emailError` to `display:none` in the first run – then you can not expect it to appear again without reversing that again …

Comment: Thanks @CBroe.That explains a lot.

Comment: Was that it? The display:none was the only issue? If you don't want the spacing of the DOM to change I would hide the <span> using CSS or document.getElementById("emailError").style.visibility = 'hidden'; until an invalid email, then use visibility = 'visible';

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yes that was only the problem. I am still working on it. Will definitely give a try to your idea. Thanks